# Build Dictionary in Python Loop - List and Dictionary Comprehensions

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

I'm playing with some loops in python. I am quite familiar with using the "for" loop:

```
for x in y:
    do something
```

You can also create a simple list using a loop:

```
i = []
for x in y:
   i.append(x)
```

and then I recently discovered a nice efficient type of loop, here on Stack, to build a list (is there a name for this type of loop? I'd really like to know so I can search on it a little better):

```
[x.name for x in y]
```

Ok, that being said, I wanted to go further with the last type of loop and I tried to build a python dictionary using the same type of logic:

```
{x[row.SITE_NAME] = row.LOOKUP_TABLE for row in cursor}
```

instead of using:

```
x = {}
for row in cursor:
   x[row.SITE_NAME] = row.LOOKUP_TABLE
```

I get an error message on the equal sign telling me it's an invalid syntax. I believe in this case, it's basically telling me that equal sign is a conditional clause (==), not a declaration of a variable.

My second question is, can I build a python dictionary using this type of loop or am I way off base? If so, how would I structure it?

Comment: The name you are looking for is [`list-comprehension`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: You're getting a syntax error because you open it with a square bracket and close it with a curly bracket and because you should use a `:` instead of an `=`: `{x[row.SITE_NAME] : row.LOOKUP_TABLE for row in cursor}`

Comment: I have made [a video that covers list comprehensions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw) and it's various cousins (set and dict comprehensions, alongside generator expressions), as it comes up so much on SO. Describing it as a 'type of loop' might be underselling it a little.

Comment: comprehensions are great....keep working at it

Comment: Thanks everyone! You all answered my question very quickly and I have exactly what I am looking for! Also, I updated the title of the post for future searches.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The short form is as follows (called **dict comprehension**, as analogy to the **list comprehension**, **set comprehension** etc.):

```
x = { row.SITE_NAME : row.LOOKUP_TABLE for row in cursor }
```

so in general given some `_container` with some kind of elements and a function `_value` which for a given element returns the value that you want to add to this key in the dictionary:

```
{ _key : _value(_key) for _key in _container }
```

Comment: This is fantastic. I had a feeling this was quite the redundant question on stack, but I couldn't find the name of the loop, so my searches weren't finding the answers I was looking for. This works beautifully. I also threw in a conditional at the end (x = { row.SITE_NAME : row.LOOKUP_TABLE for row in cursor if row.LOOKUP_TABLE <> None} Much much appreciated lejlot and all the others!

Answer (score 9):

What you're using is called a list comprehension. They're pretty awesome ;)

They have a cousin called a generator expression that works like a list comprehension but instead of building the list all at once, they generate one item at a time. Hence the name generator. You can even build functions that are generators - there are plenty of questions and sites to cover that info, though.

You can do one of two things:

```
x = dict(((row.SITE_NAME, row.LOOKUP_TABLE) for row in cursor))
```

Or, if you have a sufficiently new version of Python, there is something called a dictionary comprehension - which works like a list comprehension, but produces a dictionary instead.

```
x = {row.SITE_NAME : row.LOOKUP_TABLE for row in cursor}
```

Comment: To clarify, "a sufficiently new version of Python" means 2.7+  For those using <2.7, the first option seems to be the only one available.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
x = dict((row.SITE_NAME, row.LOOKUP_TABLE) for row in cursor)
```